# Amazon AWS web framework for Python

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

I dealt with GAE before and I like simplicity of its webapp. Now I am trying to learn how to work with Amazon EC2. My question - where do I start to make a simple web application that I will be able to access form browser? I suppose I should use WSGI for this purpose. I don't want to use Django as I want to keep the application small and lightweight without unnecessary features. What can you recommend? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS and GAE are very different. GAE very strictly defines what you can and can't do in terms of development environment.  AWS gives you a server to do whatever you want with.

GAE is good when you don't want to have to figure out how all the pieces fit together to scale well.  AWS is good when you need flexibility to do whatever you want in your environment.

So to answer your question -- you can use any framework / environment you like.

Personally, I like Django/Pinax for anything requiring a user system.  You want a lighter weight system, I've heard good things about Pylons.

Here's a listing of a few others:
http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks

Since we're talking AWS, it doesn't have to be python.  Ruby on Rails is great.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, you have a lot more flexibility with Amazon than with GAE. If you want to stick with Python and would like to be able to access your app through your browser, you might consider [web2py](http://www.web2py.com/), which enables you to edit and manage your apps through a web-based IDE and admin interface (see [demo](http://www.web2py.com/demo_admin/default/site)).

web2py was designed for [ease of use and developer productivity](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/00), so it's very easy to learn and get going quickly, and you can get a lot done with very little code. Although it's easy to do simple (and even not-so-simple) things quickly and easily, if your app gets more complex, web2py can handle that too, as it is a well-integrated full-stack framework with lots of built-in functionality, including a database abstraction layer, form handling and validation, access control, web services, and easy Ajax integration.

web2py runs on GAE out of the box, and web2py apps are portable from GAE to other platforms without requiring any code changes. However, if you're looking for a simple, scalable cloud hosting option with more flexibility than GAE, you might take a look at the new [DotCloud](http://www.dotcloud.com/) (still in beta), which actually [runs on EC2](http://docs.dotcloud.com/static/faq/#where-is-dotcloud-hosted). There's a [demo web2py app](http://www.web2py.dotcloud.com) running there now, and a [tutorial](http://docs.dotcloud.com/static/tutorials/web2py/) explaining the simple deployment process.

If you have any questions about web2py, you'll get lots of help from the friendly and responsive [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/web2py). I know some of the users have hosted web2py apps on EC2. For example, this [demo Q&A site](http://beta.qa-stack.com/) powered by web2py is hosted on EC2.

Comment: Can I access nltk in web2py?

Comment: Yes, you can use any Python library that works with Python 2.5-2.7.