# Amazon AWS - Python webframework - dynamodb

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, web-frameworks

I've done a lot of research for Google App engine. I ended up with webapp2. Now we realized that AWS has many advantages over GAE for our project.

I feel a little bit overwhelmed because there is so much information about AWS.
I ended up with the nosql dynamoDB solution.

Now I really love lightweight frameworks like webapp2 , its really simple and easy to use. It also don't hide post and get from you.

Now does it makes sense to use webapp2 for AWS ? Mabye there other frameworks that would fit better for our project. 
*(We want to go in a filehosting direction)*

I mean there are literally 50 frameworks for python. And I didn't find a chart with pro/cons.

The last frameworks that I investigated are : web2py , pylon(now pyramids?) and tornado.

To be honest I am really confused.

So if I want to have a lightweight framework for AWS would you recommend me to stay with webapp2?

Resources:

[Amazon AWS web framework for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971635/amazon-aws-web-framework-for-python)

**Edit #1**

Now it's a decision between tornado and webapp2. considering that I want to use dynamoDB.

Answer (score 1):

Tornado is a fast non-blocking web server itself. It's easy to write simple apps in a few minutes, but it has nothing AFAIK like templates, views, etcetera. If you want to serve files it would be very quick to connect a tornado server together with boto (https://github.com/boto/boto) and use dynamoDB or S3.

On the other hand, pylons (now pyrmaid) and we2py are full web application frameworks with no web server. In fact, they come with a lightweight development server (at least pylons), but if you want to put up a site in AWS you should use something like nginx (http://nginx.org/), apache or some other wsgi server (http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/).

If you want to go for a lightweight framework and use python, I'd go for web2py, easy to configure and build apps. (A curious note: it used to be a single .py file) you can try it online: http://www.web2py.com/demo_admin/default/site

Regarding webapp2 I've never used it, but I've heard it's similar to Appengine web framework. So if you're comfortable with it stay there.

Either direction, boto is the python interface for AWS so if you choose python, you'll have to check it out. It is actively mantained.

Comment: Thanks, I still don't understand the whole system yet. I only know how GAE works. I already saw boto. What I know is that it's the equivalent of the GAE sdk for AWS. Tornado looks exactly like webapp2, but many features are not available for dynamoDB.(async) Just curious , what do you mean with "comes together with a server"?   In GAE i just made some handlers with post/get and i could deploy the app.

Comment: Ah okay nevermind. Webapp2 comes with WSGI, I just never knew what it was. Now it's a decision between tornado and webapp2.